# Is there a way to efficiently check two huge arrays for matching elements

Tags: arrays, swift

I have 2 500,000 count arrays of strings. is there a more efficient way to check if they have elements that match then:

```
let array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
let array2 = ["d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]

var maching = [0]

for element1 in array1 {
    for element2 in array2 {
        if element1 == element1 {
            maching.append(element1)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Will the arrays be sorted like they are in your example?

Comment: Also, will there be duplicates in either array? If so, do you just want the unique matching elements?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, they are arrays of strings, and there are more than likely duplicates.

Comment: @Zackattack08 And are the duplicates important for you? Do you want multiple matches for duplicates? Is the order important?

Comment: No, I don't care about the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

If elements are `Hashable` (strings are) and if we can ignore duplicates and ordering, then using `Set` is the easiest solution:

```
let matching = Set(array1).intersection(Set(array2))
```

Depending on the nature of the data, we could come with an even better solution, e.g. an interval tree. The more information we have, the better solution can be designed. However, an optimal solution specific to one use case will be much more complex.

Comment: They are arrays of strings, I should have clarified.

Comment: Then this solution will work. If we had sorted arrays of numbers, it would be even simpler.

Comment: Thank you, it did work for what I needed it for

Comment: It's a tad inefficient to create two sets if you're just looking for the intersection. One set is sufficient.

Comment: you can pass any collection to the intersection method as long as its element is equal to the set element. `Set(array1).intersection(array2)`